# How does this piece of code work (I think the correct term is 'currying')

Tags: python, class, methods, overriding, currying

I am having a hard time understanding how this code works:

```
class add(int):
    
    def __call__(self, int):
        return add(self + int)

result = add(2)
print(result(4))
```

The int 2 seems to get stored inside result (not sure if that is the case), such that when we print(result), the output is 2. When print(result(4)) is ran, the output becomes 6. My question is: why is this?

Is the number 2, in fact, being stored inside result? If we instantiate the add class without an argument, the result variable will output the number 0. What is happening here under the hood?

I want to understand why calling result(2)(3)(4) outputs 9.

Answer (score 1):

What this class does, it gives integers an ability to be called as a function, so that `a(b)` actually means `a+b`. Imagine one day this feature is added to the python interpreter. Then you could write `2(3)` and get `5`. But that `5` is still callable, so we can do `5(4)` and get `9`, or, chained together, `2(3)(4) => 9`.

In actual python this is not possible (number literals are always `int`), so we have to explicitly name our class (as in `add(2)(3)(4)`), but the principle remains the same.

"Currying" is not what's happening here.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that clarification about the currying.

Answer (score 0):

`add` is a class that subclasses `int`. As such, it behaves exactly as we would expect `int` instances to behave. So, for example, its "default"y value is 0. That is why `print(add())` is 0 (since `int()` is 0).

Now, we implemented the `__add__` method. According to the [data-model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__), the `__add__` method allows instances of classes that implement it to be callable, ie be used to the left of `()`, with or without argument.

Since you allowed `__call__` to accept an argument and you add this argument to the value that the instance currently represents (remember that `add` instances behave just like a normal `int` would), we can call instances of `add` with an argument and expect the behavior you observed.

To recap, `add(2)` gives us an object that represents the integer `2` (just like `int(2)` would) with the added functionality of being able to call it with an argument that will be added to its own value (so `add(2)(3)` is just `2 + 3`).

We can add some `print`s to see what is going on, and it is better to not use the name `int` in the definition of `__call__` since we don't want to shadow the type `int` (that the `add` class subclasses). Ignore the call to `super().__init__()` if you are not familiar with it already, it is there to allow us to print the message).

```py
class add(int):
    def __init__(self, own_value):
        print(f"Created 'add' with own_value {own_value}")
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, number):
        print(f"Inside __call__ with number {number}, will return new 'add' with own_value {self + number}")
        return add(self + number)


result = add(2)
print(result(4))
```

outputs

```
Created 'add' with own_value 2
Inside __call__ with number 4, will return new 'add' with own_value 6
Created 'add' with own_value 6
6
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Very helpful and informative!